# Unable to receive data payload message on onMessageReceived when phone is locked

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Unable to receive data payload message on onMessageReceived when phone is locked. I am using firebase admin nodejs SDK to send data message.Please help!!.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/6143482

Comment: I tried with following data message json                                                                 var message={
 
    "topic":topic,
    
    "data" : {
      "volume" : "3.21.15",
      "contents" : "content for test"
    },
    "android":{
      "priority":"high"
    }
    
      
    
  }                                                                                                                      
   It works fine when phone screen awake ,once phone screen locked message does not comes in onMessageReceived event.

Answer (score 0):

we should have a payload like:

```
{
    ...,
    "data": {
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      ...
    } 
}
```

to receive a onMessageReceived event when app locked